# Create matrix operations to compute $[y1, y2 x1, x2]$ from vectors $[x1,x2,1]$ and $[y1, y2, 1]$

Tags: matrices, problem-solving, matrix-equations

I want to create a series of matrix operations that would allow me to combine the vectors $[x1,x2,1]$, $[y1, y2, 1]$ without using a Hadamard product to produce $[y1, y2 x1, x2] = [y1, y2, 1] \circ [1, x1,x2]$. The vectors can be rearranged in any way, i.e. $[1, x1,x2]$, and use of matrix multiplications, additions, etc... can be used, but the diagonal function or the Hadamard product cannot.
Is this possible?

The problem that I want to solve is trying to "simplify" the operations.
$$
x = [x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_n]^T \in [0,1] \\
y = 1- x \\
x_p = [1|x]\\
y_p=[y|1]\\
r=x_p \circ y_p = [y_1,y2*x1,...,y_n*x_{n-1},x_n]
$$

You can already rewrite $y_p$ as:
$$
y_p = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-I & 1
\end{bmatrix}x_p \\
y_p = T x_p \\
r=x_p \circ T x_p
$$

But I feel like you should be able to "simplify" the problem further

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: bot is wrong. question is clear.